# Hebrew in SMS messages

Tags: php, curl, sms

im using Voicetrading to send SMSs via a custom application ive built, english is great, but when it comes to hebrew, i get blank messages.

I use this code:

```
  $ch = curl_init($smsRequest);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $smsRequest);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset="utf-8"'));

   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

do you have any idea how to solve it? or is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to the gateway service: Unicode text messages can be a special service. You should talk to the gateway provider - they are not offering any info on this on their public pages - and ask for the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

If Voicetrading do not offer Unicode messages, may I suggest you look at [BulkSMS](http://www.bulksms.com/), who do support this?

Full disclosure: I work for BulkSMS